# Create Engine(SQLalchemy) for GCP database in a python script

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, sqlalchemy

I want my python script to read data from GCP database but I don't know how to make a connection.

Generally when we connect to local Database we do something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5432/django_app')    
data = pd.read_sql_query('select * from "ABC"', con=engine)
```

basic layout to connect to a local database:

```
dialect+driver://username:password@host:port/database
```

but how can I do the same with the database residing on GCP.
Do I need to pass my instance name instead of localhost ?

Comment: you have to replace localhost with the instance IP @Rahul Sharma

Comment: I did that and it throws this error

`OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
 Is the server running on host "Instance_IP_address" and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
`

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue?

Comment: @WebDev.. Yes but I did that on my own

Comment: Ok, what solved the issue for you? This would be helpful for others facing the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:password@<public IP address>/postgres')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this documentation and below is the part of it.

```
# The SQLAlchemy engine will help manage interactions, including automatically
# managing a pool of connections to your database
db = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    # Equivalent URL:
    # mysql+pymysql://<db_user>:<db_pass>@/<db_name>?unix_socket=/cloudsql/<cloud_sql_instance_name>
    sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL(
        drivername='mysql+pymysql',
        username=db_user,
        password=db_pass,
        database=db_name,
        query={
            'unix_socket': '/cloudsql/{}'.format(cloud_sql_connection_name)
        }
    ),
    # ... Specify additional properties here.
    # ...
}
```

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/cloud-sql/mysql/sqlalchemy/main.py

Comment: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "/cloudsql/INSTANCE_NAME" to address: Unknown host
This error was received

Comment: can you post the code and output as well, I can help better.

Comment: make sure you have proper proxies and internet access set on the machine you are running it.

Comment: `import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

db = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL(
        drivername='postgresql',
        username="postgres",
        password="password",
        database="postgres",
        query={'host': '/cloudsql/{}'.format("Instance_name")} ))`

Comment: replace instance_name string with actual instance name of the server '/cloudsql/{}'.format("your_actual_db_server_name")}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193616/discussion-between-prashant-and-rahul-sharma).

Comment: I did that but obviously I can't show you, that's why I replaced my actual instance name with `Instance_name`

Comment: is your instance publicly accessible or accessible from your private network?

Answer (score 0):

We can connect to it by just replacing `host:port` with public IP address

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:password@<public IP address>/postgres')    
# dialect+driver://username:password@publicIPaddress/database
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to follow the steps below to connect to your postgres database, if it is installed on a Google Cloud Platform VM instance:

1. Log on to console.cloud.google.com and select the Project which contains your VM instance having the database.
2. Pull down the main menu from the top left and go to *Network Settings -> VPC Network -> Firewall Rules*.
3. Create a new firewall rule using the button on top of the page.
4. Give the rule some name e.g. `postgres` and in the field *Protocols and Ports*, select *tcp* and enter the port number as *5432* (since you are using the default port as mentioned in your post) and create it.
5. Pull down the main menu from the top left and go to *Compute -> Compute Engine -> VM Instances*.
6. In the VM Instances page shown, note down the *External IP* for the instance where your database resides.
7. Click on your VM instance and then click on the Edit button on top.
8. In the *Network tags* field, add the rule name given in step 4 above viz. `postgres` and save the changes.
9. Now start your VM instance (you may need to perform step 6. to check the *External IP* again if you are not using a static *External IP*)
10. You will now be able to connect to your database using:

`engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:password@<external_ip_noted_in_point9>:5432/django_app')`